# Calling asmx service method using HttpClient

Tags: c#, httpclient, asmx

I want call asmx web service method to use `HttpClient` and i have tried with this code but it returned 404 status code.How can i call asmx service using `HttpClient`.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress=new Uri(@"http://../vbtTest/WS/BimserStratejikPlanService.asmx");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("AktarimListesi").Result;

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{ 

}
```

Comment: You can't, unless you reconstruct the entire SOAP message expected by the service. BTW SOAP uses `PUT`, not `GET`. Use WCF and add a service reference to your project. A 404 error though means the URL is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP `404` error means that the server could not find the requested resource.

This is possibly down to a incorrect URL or you are using an incorrect HTTP Verb (GET) as suggested by Panagiotis Kanavos.

Answer (score 0):

This URL "http://../vbtTest/WS/BimserStratejikPlanService.asmx" - I'm presuming you're trying to execute this from within an ASPX page.  ".." as a prefix will not work.  You need to provide an absolute URL.